# My Ajax Doesn't Show Notification Message

Tags: php, ajax

I'm writing code to show notification by using Ajax to access database. However, when I refresh the Home page, there isn't any change to my page even after I've written 'alert' command. Please help me how to solve this kind of problem.

PS: I also have another ajax code written in my project and their working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('Jobs/jobNotification');?>",
      type:"POST",
      dataType:"json",
      data:{},
      success: function(data){
        alert(data.msg);
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: @Barmar, It shows '$ is not defined'

Comment: That means you didn't load the jQuery library before this script.